# What is MigrationProxy in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. Brief explanation of **ActiveRecord MigrationProxy** in rails migration?
2. When it will be used in rails application?
3. What is the use of Migration Proxy?

Comment: Its just an implementation detail of how rails loads the migrations when you run `rails db:migrate` and not something you actually need to be concerned with if you are just creating rails apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MigrationProxy is used to defer loading of the actual migration classes until they are needed](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/MigrationProxy).

It is currently only used [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7085b5467e5a5886f6f6cbffcd8de86fa0ebea01/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L1116), as an *internal implementation detail* in rails.

This is a performance optimisation - so the code for each migration is only loaded if needed. (Which is determined by the timestamp of the migration, and the schema version of your database.)